# Is there any API in j2me to make silent http requests without the connection selection prompt?

Tags: java-me, midp, series-40

In my j2me application, I am trying to fetch some data over the network but I want to do it silently if the connection is available. I know that user settings are available for prompting/not prompting for IAP selection dialog but I want that even if the user has selected "Ask first", the request be made silently in my application.

Is there some API in s40 platform to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

This is about MIDP security rather than the APIs. The [current security policy](http://library.developer.nokia.com/topic/Java_Developers_Library/GUID-F5EAF83A-0553-4504-BCB8-752EBE86A60D.html) by default asks for a prompt on network access. You can bypass them if your application is manufacturer or operator signed.